# Output Only Entries from Entry Field Related to a Category

Tags: relations, category

I have a section called "lunchMenu" that contains an entries field ("menuItems").  Each entry in "menuItems" is related to a category in the category group ("foodCategory").  I would like to loop through each of the entries only in "lunchMenu" and output them within their respective categories.

When I loop through the entries field alone, everything works just fine.  However, when I add the relatedTo parameter to sort by category, I get entries that are not present in this section's entry field.

Here's the code I'm using - any help would be appreciated.  I think I'm not understanding the use of the relatedTo correctly.

```
{% set food = craft.categories.group('foodCategory') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('lunchMenu') %}

    {% for entry in entries %}
        {% for category in food %}
        {{ category.title }}
            {% for item in entry.menuItems.relatedTo(category) %}
                    {{ item.title }}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```